# How cold should I let my home get in the winter for my small dog?

Tags: dogs, temperature, winter

My home gets cold in the winter. What temperature should I heat my house to for my dog's safety and comfort.

I have a small dog with tons of fur (a Pomeranian). She sleeps in a plastic crate with two blankets.

It would be great if you an point to a reputable source. I searched online and could not find any.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's something you can safely ignore. If it's warm enough for you, your dog should be happy as well.

Just offer a retreat, e.g. with a snuggly blanket or similar on an isolated bed (if the ground is colder, e.g. stone tiles) and let the dog decide.

It's easy to say owning Huskies but even our dogs won't just accept any temperature or condition if they have the choice. They'll hide in the couch or in my bed, if they think it's more comfortable there.

Comment: Thanks. I sleep with a thick comforter and my dog's room is on the ground floor which is colder than my room so I'm hesitant to compare my comfort to theirs.

Comment: @VivekMaharajh Maybe use numbers. How cold does it really get? :)

Comment: Right now it goes down to 60. In the coldest day I'm guessing itll go to 50.

Comment: @VivekMaharajh Wouldn't expect that to be an issue especially considering the dog isn't shorthaired.